# How to source a script in every panes and windows of a specific tmux session

Tags: tmux

I have a shell script specific for a project which create environment variables, aliases and run some commands.

I want to create a tmux session for this project which will source my shell script when creating a new pane or window in the tmux session.

How can I specify tmux to source a file or run command in every new panes or windows of a specific session?

Answer (score 4):

Set the `default-command` option for the session to run your shell (I'll assume it is `bash`) with the `--rcfile` option to use your shell script as the initialization file

```
set-option -g default-command "bash --rcfile yourscript.sh"
```

Since `--rcfile` replaces `.bashrc`, you add `source .bashrc` to the beginning of `yourscript.sh`. If you would ordinarily start a login shell in a `tmux` window, add `source .bash_profile` instead.

---

To have separate default commands for different sessions, you need to create the session first, then set its default command.

```
tmux new-session -s projectA
tmux set-option -s -t projectA default-command "bash --rcfile projectA.sh"
```

You might want to define a shell function to simplify setting up a new session, something like

```
new_session () {
    tmux new-session -s "$1"
    tmux set-option -s -t "$1" default-command "bash --rcfile $1.sh"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but how can I have different ``default-command`` according on the name of the session created with ``tmux new-session -s name``?

I'd like to have one ``default-command`` using ``projectA.sh`` if I run ``tmux new-session -s projectA`` and another ``default-command``using ``projectB.sh`` if I run ``tmux new-session -s projectB``

Comment: See the documentation for `set-option`; you should be able to specify the session you want change the default command for.

Comment: The man page of tmux doesn't help me. I can't configure session option to source a script. 

Here are my config files:
 - .tmux.conf:
``set-option -s -t "projectA" default-command "bash --rcfile projectA.sh"``

Comment: Here are my config files:

 - .tmux.conf:
``set-option -s -t "projectA" default-command "bash --rcfile projectA.sh"``

 - projectA.sh:
``export ENV="A"
export PROJECT="~/projectA"
alias cdproject="cd $PROJECT"``
If I run ``tmux``without parameter option: ``/root/.tmux.conf:1: session not found: projectA                                                                                                           
/root/.tmux.conf:1: couldn't set 'default-command'``